# jQuery plugin for page-jump dropdown

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I have a page title on a page.
When I hover that title, I want it to turn into "dropdown-able" effect.
When I click it, it should dropdown a jumplist with links to other pages.
Not to mention, when I click something in the list, it should change the page, a custom callback is okay.
After that, it should turn back into plain text, page title.

Does anyone know the best plugin to fit the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a very basic (unstyled) example how I would create it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ECMxf/1/

Answer (score 0):

What did you thought about; [jQuery-ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Or just build your own, its not that hard(in my opinion its a thing to start with in jQuery)?